# what is the os.close(3) for?

Tags: python, linux

What is the os.close(3) for?

I am reading the *python cookbook 2nd* chapter 2.9, it explains how the python zip file work. There is one snippet of code in it I don't really got it.

```
import zipfile, tempfile, os, sys
handle, filename = tempfile.mkstemp('.zip')
os.close(handle)  # <- handle is int 3 here
z = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'w')
z.writestr('hello.py', 'def f(): return "hello world from "+__file__\n')
z.close()
sys.path.insert(0, filename)
import hello
print hello.f()
os.unlink(filename)
```

os.close() explaination in python docs:

*This function is intended for low-level I/O and must be applied to a file descriptor as returned by os.open() or pipe(). To close a “file object” returned by the built-in function open() or by popen() or fdopen(), use its close() method.*

The file descriptor in linux from 0,1 & 2 are stdin, stdout & stderror, I don't get what the fd 3 for? Even though I have read this "[What is the file descriptor 3 assigned by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41421/what-is-the-file-descriptor-3-assigned-by-default) ".

I comment the `os.close(handle)` out, but the output make no different.

Comment: You got the `handle` from `tempfile.mkstemp`, so why don't you read the docs for that? Clearly you're closing the temporary file, why would you expect it to be one of the three standard file handles in/out/err? Also, you should read the style guide: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing magic about `3` -- if your program was started with FD 3 already in use, or was previously assigned that handle number when opening another file (and that file had not been closed), then you would have gotten a different handle number assigned here.

Comment: One thing not touched on by the answers is that while you can unlink a file (i.e. remove its name from the directory listing), its contents will not be gone while somebody still has a handle on it. In particular, the space is not freed. (Usual real-life case is "I deleted a 3 gig logfile, why did I not get 3 gig free space back?" -- "Because your prorgam still has the deleted file open".)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, while that's certainly true, I'm not sure that it's germane to the question at hand (and thus that a discursion would be topical).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though Python mostly deals in "file objects", these are an abstraction around OS-level file handles; when actually reading or writing content to a file (or network stream, or other file-like object) at the operating system level, one passes the OS the handle number associated with the file with which one wants to interact. Thus, every file object in Python that's actually backed by an OS-level file handle has such a file descriptor number associated.

File handles are stored in a table, each associated with an integer. On Linux, you can look at the directory `/proc/self/fds` (substituting a PID number for `self` to look at a different process) to see which handles have which numbers for a given process.

`handle, filename = tempfile.mkstemp('.zip'); os.close(handle)`, thus, closes the OS-level file handle which was returned to you by `mkstemp`.

---

By the way: It's important to note that there's absolutely nothing special about the number 3, and that there is no default or conventional behavior for same implemented at the operating system level; it just happened to be the next available position in the file handle table when `mkstemp` was called (or, to be more precise, when the C standard library implementation of `mkstemp` called the OS-level syscall `open`).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting file descriptor 3 because in this case it is the next available file descriptor. As you mentioned, `stdin` (0), `stdout` (1) and `stderr` (2) are automatically opened for you. The link you cited ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41421/what-is-the-file-descriptor-3-assigned-by-default ) points this out, too.

Comment: It's not exactly guaranteed that FD 3 will be assigned to the first file handle a program opens; it may be inheriting more or fewer descriptors than the standard set from its parent process (the former certainly being more common than the latter).

Comment: ...for instance, a program where a guarantee of running only one instance is externally enforced via a `flock()`-style lockfile will be invoked inheriting a handle on that lock.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good points, and apparently the OP understands your more comprehensive answer.